# How do I aggregate rows with an upper bound on column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.DataFrame I'd like to transform:

```
   id  values  days  time  value_per_day
0   1      15    15     1         1
1   1      20     5     2         4
2   1      12    12     3         1
```

I'd like to aggregate these into equal buckets of 10 days. Since `days` at time 1 is larger than 10, this should spill into the next row, having the `value/day` of the 2nd row an average of the 1st and the 2nd.

Here is the resulting output, where `(values, 0) = 15*(10/15) = 10` and `(values, 1) = (5+20)/2`:

```
   id  values  days  value_per_day
0   1      10    10         1.0
1   1      25    10         2.5
2   1      10    10         1.0
3   1       2     2         1.0
```

I've tried `pd.Grouper`:

```
df.set_index('days').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='10D', label='right'), 'id']).agg({'values': 'mean'})

Out[146]:
            values
days    id        
5 days  1       16
15 days 1       10
```

But I'm clearly using it incorrectly.

**csv for convenience:**

```
id,values,days,time  
1,10,15,1  
1,20,5,2  
1,12,12,3
```

Comment: I don't understand the `value` column.  If you say that row 2 should be an average of row 1 & 2 due to the spill over, row 3's value is `10` (changed from 12, where as row 1 didn't change) and row 4's is `2` (not an average of 12 / 2)?

Comment: You are correct, I will update the table

Comment: @Idlehands is it still not clear? I admit my calculation was wrong initially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice: this is a time cost solution

```
newdf=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.days))
v=np.arange(sum(df.days))//10
dd=pd.DataFrame({'value_per_day': newdf.groupby(v).value_per_day.mean(),'days':np.bincount(v)})
dd
Out[102]: 
   days  value_per_day
0    10            1.0
1    10            2.5
2    10            1.0
3     2            1.0
dd.assign(value=dd.days*dd.value_per_day)
Out[103]: 
   days  value_per_day  value
0    10            1.0   10.0
1    10            2.5   25.0
2    10            1.0   10.0
3     2            1.0    2.0
```

I did not include groupby id here, if you need that for your real data, you can do for loop with `df.groupby(id)` , then apply above steps within the for loop

Comment: Impressive solution, this has been very helpful. Thanks @Wen :)

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal yw~ :-)